# CURL gives error 'Could not resolve host' on first several attempts, then success (CentOS7)

Tags: bash, curl

I've encountered a curious situation and now wonder if anyone can explain or guess the reason for this behavior: when I CURL my endpoint it responses with 'Could not resolve host' the first several attempts (2-5 times in some cases), but then finally it returns with expected response without me changing literally anything.

```
bash-4.4$ curl http://example.com/welcome/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com
bash-4.4$ curl http://example.com/welcome/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com
bash-4.4$ curl http://example.com/welcome/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com
bash-4.4$ curl http://example.com/welcome/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: example.com
bash-4.4$ curl http://example.com/welcome/
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Comment: Most likely you have a congested DNS which does not answer in time.  Get the address and add it into your local hosts file.  Or call curl with the IP directly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've been meaning to call curl with IP, the problem is I need to curl a subdomain (my.example.com). I guess I'll look into hosts file.